# Wordpress - Include static image after every X post through wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a somewhat complicated [design](https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod_object_assets/assets/154831508102193/rs-hifi-mockup-managementteam-02.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXM6FRIC5QVSA63Q&Expires=1468956667&Signature=GBNRFn7s6dRpwRYDqFXthpHBnqg%3D#_=_).

I want to use a CPT to output it. This is my CPT in the wp_query:

```
/**
 * Management Team Shortcode
**/
function team_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'management-team',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if ( !empty( $posts ) )  {

        $flag = 0;
        foreach ($posts as $counter => $p) {
            $counter++;

            if ( $flag <= 2 ) {
                $flag++;                
            }

            $role = get_field( "role" );
            $name = get_field( "team_member_name" );
            $bio = get_field( "bio" );
            $profile = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $p->ID, 'full'     );
            $flip = get_field( "flip_content" );

            $html_out = '<article class="team-member">';
               // Do stuff with each post here

            if ( $flag % 2 == 0  ) {
                //add image after second post like
                $html_out .= '<img src="http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/rawafid/wp-content/themes/rawafid-systems/assets/img/mt-1.jpg" alt="Safety Whistle" />';
            }

            if ( $counter % 6 == 0 ) {
                $flag = 0;
                //add image after sixth post like
                $html_out .= '<img src="http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/rawafid/wp-content/themes/rawafid-systems/assets/img/mt-2.jpg" alt="Safety Whistle" />';
            }

            $html_out .= '<div class="meta-team"><h6>' . $role . '</h6>' . '<h4>' . $name . '</h4>' . '<p>' . $bio . '</p></div>';
            $html_out .= '</article>';
        }
    } else {
         // No results
        $html_out = 'No Management Team Members Found.';
    }

    return $html_out;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_management_team', 'team_query' );
```

After 2 posts I'd like to add a static img and after 4 posts another static and after 2 more posts another static img, etc.

I'm open to suggestions on a better approach.

I'm trying to think of an alternative method. Maybe using Visual composer to build a grid?

Comment: Hey Daren, would it be possible to clarify, how many static images will be displayed?
As far as I understand, after 2 posts there will be static image, correct?
Or after the 4th post the image has change?

Thank yoi

Comment: Both. It would be 2, 4 , 2 ,4, 2, 4, etc. This sounds weird I know. This is what the design looks like [link](http://imgur.com/a/uGKh4)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Darren here is the logic, I think that you can modify my functions and implement it in your code.

```
/**
 * Management Team Shortcode
**/
function team_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'management-team',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if ( !empty( $posts ) )  {

        $flag = 0;
        foreach ($posts as $counter => $p) {
            $counter++;

            if ( $flag <= 2 ) {
                $flag++;                
            }

            $title = get_the_title($p->ID);
            $link = get_the_permalink($p->ID);
            $featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $p->ID, 'full'     );

            $html_out = '<article class="recent-project" style="background: url(' . $featured_img . ') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">';
               // Do stuff with each post here

            if ( $flag % 2 == 0  ) {
                //add image after second post like
                // $html .= <img src="css/images/myimage1.png" alt="" />
            }

            if ( $counter % 6 == 0 ) {
                $flag = 0;
                //add image after sixth post like
                // $html .= <img src="css/images/myimage2.png" alt="" />
            }

            $html_out .= '<div class="container"><div class="meta-project"><h6>Latest Project</h6>' . '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>' . '<a class="btn btn-lg btn-tertiary" href="' . $link . '">' . 'Discover' . '</a></div></div>';
            $html_out .= '</article>';
        }
    } else {
         // No results
        echo "Nothing to show";
    }

    return $html_out;
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Which `if` statement would I start adding in my `team_query`?

Comment: I have changed my code. You should replace comments in ifs with your images. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Hey, the content is not outputting. I'm getting `Undefined variable: html`, did you mean `$html_out` instead of `$html`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, replace html with html_out.

Comment: So I updated my OP. The variables I'm using are from Advanced Custom Fields. Here's a [link](http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/rawafid/about/management-team/) demo. I got the first img to appear, but there are no posts.

Comment: any ideas? How could I debug this?